# Cannot run mvn vaadin:compile on Vaadin Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, vaadin, pom.xml

When I run the command : mvn vaadin:compile I get this error :

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.039s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 20 11:35:00 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'vaadin' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (D:\Users\etantaou\.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

I made a search and I found that I have to add this to my pom.xml under  :

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
      <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                  vaadin-maven-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <versionRange>
                  [1.0.2,)
                </versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>clean</goal>
                                    <goal>resources</goal>
                                    <goal>update-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                                    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <ignore></ignore>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                  gwt-maven-plugin
                </artifactId>
                <versionRange>
                  [${gwt.plugin.version},)
                </versionRange>
                <goals>
                  <goal>resources</goal>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
                </goals>
              </pluginExecutionFilter>
              <action>
                <ignore></ignore>
              </action>
            </pluginExecution>
          </pluginExecutions>
        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I added that but I still get the error. Is there any jar or something that I have to add to make this work ?

For information I'm trying to create custom widgets on my Vaadin project. They say [here](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/addons.maven.html) I have to run vaadin:compile to compile WidgetSet.

Answer (score 3):

I am not an expert in maven but this is my `pom.xml` and it works. Just make sure you change the `<version>` to whatever version of Vaadin you are using (mine is 7.1.12).

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</directory>
                        </fileset>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/gwt-unitCache</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.1.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <hostedWebapp>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/VAADIN/widgetsets</hostedWebapp>
                    <noServer>true</noServer>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/</runTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: This worked for me and should be chosen as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have put the plugin configuration into pluginManagement section, which simply defines some default configuration but doesn't actually use the plugin.

You need to now define the plugin inside the `<build><plugins>` element. Something like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: *`<!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->`*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`pom.xml` from Vaadin's demo](https://github.com/vaadin/valo-demo/blob/master/pom.xml).

Maybe the `goals` aren't correct, try the following:

```
<goals>
    <goal>resources</goal>
    <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
    <goal>compile</goal>
    <goal>update-theme</goal>
    <goal>compile-theme</goal>
</goals>
```