# Vaadin project compilation and execution

Tags: java, gwt, vaadin

I have a little question on how Vaadin and GWT works. When I develop my views using Vaadin or GWT I only write Java code. But when does my Java is generated into HTML and JS files ? During the compilation of my project or on runtime ?

I tryed to find this information on the Vaadin guide but I didn't found anything yet :(

edit:
Not really duplicate of [Cannot run mvn vaadin:compile on Vaadin Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530618/cannot-run-mvn-vaadincompile-on-vaadin-maven-project), I don't have a problem with the code or execution of my project but for myself, I just wanna know when does Vaadin or GWT generates its HTML and JS files ? During the Maven build itslef or on runtime, on demand only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot run mvn vaadin:compile on Vaadin Maven project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22530618/cannot-run-mvn-vaadincompile-on-vaadin-maven-project)

Comment: Not really, I don't have a problem with the code or execution of my project but for myself, I just wanna know when does Vaadin or GWT generates its HTML and JS files ? During the Maven build itslef or on runtime, on demand only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vaadin you have to distinct two things:

- Backend is written in Java and is run on a servlet engine like Tomcat, Glasfish,...
- Frontend is written in Java, GWT or Javascript
- For the backend the java compiler just creates the .class files from the .java source code
- For the frontend, the java code is GWT based, and thus compiled into highly optimized javascript code, this happens in the "Compile/Build Widgetset" phase ob your build process
- Frontend code can also be written in javascript, this is then passed as is to the browser, but with the addition of some logic to connect the JS components to it's serverside part.
  The generated frontend javascript code is then also responsible to build the html content.

[The Vaadin Architecture](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/architecture.html)

Comment: Thank you for explanation, but for the frontend, when does "jaxb2-basics-annotate" ? On project build itself ? Or on execution/runtime when a user ask for a page in it's browser for example ?

Comment: Where do you use that annotation?

Comment: Sorry, very bad copy/paste, my fault ! I mean:  for the frontend, when does "For the frontend, the java code is GWT based, and thus compiled into highly optimized javascript code" ? On project build itself ? Or on execution/runtime when a user ask for a page in it's browser for example ?

Comment: The javascript code is generated during the project build itself, in the "Compile Widgetset" step. Per default it compiles 3-4 variants of the JS code (IE, Webkit, Firefox, ...)

Comment: Ok, and the HTML files are generated on demand by the user, using th previously generated JS ?

Comment: There are no html files at all, just a small bootstrap which loads all .js files, and these then manipulate the DOM of the page(s). There is normally no second html page loaded, but everything is done via DOM manipulation. (Which makes the pages non seachable by google or other search engines)